# Troubleshooting PDO: Error not caught when executing prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, try-catch

I have run into a problem using PDO because an error was not caught.

The code is simple and works just fine, I'll just include a sample to avoid confusion:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO somedatetable (something) 
        VALUES (:something) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE something=:something';

$values = array(":something" => $something);

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);    
    $stmt->execute($values);    
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n";
}
```

The code works fine, however when working on a new module, I ran into a problem that no records were added or modified and no error was caught.

`$stmt` returned `false` but I did not have a clue why or how to find the error.

The solution was simple in the end, I was using a limited MySQL user that did not have write permissions to the table. These errors always displayed right away when using mysql, but using PDO I do not know how to get to them.

How do I get PHP / PDO to display or catch these kind of database errors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`PDO::errorInfo()`](http://php.net/pdo.errorinfo) or [`PDOStatement->errorInfo()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.errorinfo)

As for exceptions, check the docs for [*"Errors and error handling"* in PDO](http://php.net/pdo.error-handling). Exceptions aren't thrown by default, which is why you might want to enable them.

See as well:

- [My PDO statement doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32648371/367456)

Comment: Thanks, that tells me exactly what I need to know. One more question though, why is the error not caught?

Comment: You said it returned false, that means it was caught ;-)

Comment: Ummmmmmmm, what is the point of having a catch statement then if it does not show the message? I thought the whole point of that was to get rid of these if (success) else combinations...

Comment: Or is (PDOException $e) just wrong? I Must have caught the wrong thing but I am learning :)