# Why does this PDO statement silently fail?

Tags: php, pdo

This is my PHP SQL statement and it's returning false while var dumping

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO users(full_name, e_mail, username, password) VALUES (:fullname, :email, :username, :password)');
$result = $sql->execute(array(
                    ':fullname' => $_GET['fullname'], 
                    ':email' => $_GET['email'], 
                    ':username' => $_GET['username'],
                    ':password' => $password_hash));
```

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: Another thing to note here is, sanitize your $_GET data before passing them to array inside of the execute method. I know this is beyond the question, but can't help it, it's my programming OCD :P

Answer (score 79, accepted):

#### TL;DR

1. Always have `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` option set to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` in your PDO connection code. It will let the database tell you what the actual problem is, be it with SQL, data, server or database. Also, make sure you can see PHP errors in general.
2. Always replace every PHP variable in the SQL query with a question mark, and execute the query using [**prepared statement**](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select#prepare). It will help to avoid syntax errors of all sorts.

#### Explanation

Sometimes your PDO code produces an error like `Call to a member function execute()` or similar. Or even without any error but the query doesn't work all the same. It means that your query failed to execute. The reasons can be split into four categories:

1. The code didn't execute at all
2. The input data is wrong.
3. There was an error during execution.
4. It was executed successfully but a correct result is not observed due to some observational error.

In order to deal with first two you need to use some debugging techniques, that's out of scope of this answer, but you can get some hints from my article on [PHP debugging](https://phpdelusions.net/basic_principles_of_web_programming#debugging).

The 3rd category is the most common one. But easiest to investigate, because every time a query fails, MySQL has an error message that **explains the reason**. Unfortunately, by default such errors are not transferred to PHP, and all you have is a silence or a cryptic error message mentioned above.  Hence it is very important to configure PHP and PDO to report you MySQL errors. And once you get the error message, it will be a no-brainer to fix the issue.

In order to get the detailed information about the problem, either put the following line in your code right after connect

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

(where `$dbh` is the name of your PDO instance variable) or - better - add this parameter as a [connection option](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql#example). After that all database errors will be translated into PDO exceptions which, if left alone, would act just as regular PHP errors.

After getting the error message, you have to read and comprehend it. It sounds too obvious, but learners often overlook the *meaning* of the error message. Yet most of time it explains the problem pretty straightforward:

- Say, if it says that a particular table doesn't exist, you have to check spelling, typos, letter case. Also you have to make sure that your PHP script connects to a correct database
- Or, if it says there is an error in the SQL syntax, then you have to examine your SQL. And the problem spot is right **before** the query part cited in the error message.

You have to also *trust* the error message. If it says that number of tokens doesn't match the number of bound variables then it *is* so. Same goes for absent tables or columns. Given the choice, whether it's your own mistake or the error message is wrong, always stick to the former. Again it sounds condescending, but hundreds of questions on this very site prove this advice extremely useful.

---

Note that in order to see PDO errors, you have to be able to see PHP errors in general. To do so, you have to configure PHP depends on the site environment:

- on a **development** server it is very handy to have errors right on the screen, for which displaying errors have to be turned on:

  ```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
  ```
- while on a **live** site, all errors have to be **logged, but never shown** to the client. For this, configure PHP this way:

  ```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    ini_set('log_errors', 1);
  ```

Note that `error_reporting` should be set to `E_ALL` all the time.

Also note that despite the common delusion, **no try-catch have to be used for the error reporting**. PHP will report you PDO errors already, and in a way better form. An uncaught exception is very good for development, yet if you want to show a customized error page, still don't use try catch for this, but just set a [custom error handler](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting). In a nutshell, you don't have to treat PDO errors as something special but regard them as any other error in your code.

---

Observational errors

Sometimes there is no error but no results either. Then it means, *there is no data to match your criteria*. I've got a short answer that would help you to pinpoint the matching issue, [Having issue with matching rows in the database using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57986043/285587). Just follow this instruction, and the linked tutorial step by step and either have your problem solved or have an answerable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: How does that answer the OPs question?

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer id doesn't, but it could lead him/her to find the answer based on the error reporting suggested by "Your Common Sense" ..

Comment: @Your Common Sense : a new one on me, same issue. Root cause was setting the `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` option in the options when creating the PDO object.  Breaks in production (php 7.2.8), works in dev (php 7.2.34) !!! It is the setting of the option (not the value of the option being set) that caused a random fail in some cases.

Comment: I am facing same problem.. Ever code expect one update statement not working and not showing the error.. $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); is already in my code

Comment: @AMALBENNY there is **entire answer** above, not just one line with PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I had the same problem of not seeing any error messages from mysql. After a research it turned out that the problem has got nothing to do with PHP itself, but with mysql server configuration. The default value of the variable **lc_messages_dir** pointed to non existing directory. After adding a line in mysqld.cnf, then restarted the mysql server, and finally I was able to see the error messages. For me the following was the right one:

```
lc_messages_dir=/usr/share/mysql
```

It is described in the mysql reference manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-message-language.html