# Q [PHP]: What does this mean? -> Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: php, string, pdo

Recently I had a problem with one of my PHP codes, and made this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330657/php-pdo-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-on-boolean)
and I got a solution on that, but when applying that solution, another error came up!

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'admin_db' in C:\wamp64\www\NewKali\includes\user.inc.php on line 55
```

This error is complaining about this section of my code:

```
public function isAdmin($user){
    $userToGet = $user;

    $stmt = $this->Connect()->prepare("SELECT admin_db FROM user_secure WHERE username_db=?");
    $query1 = $stmt->execute([$userToGet]);

    if(!$query1)
    {
      die("Execute query error, because: ". print_r($this->Connect()->errorInfo(),true) );
    }else{
        foreach ( $stmt->fetch() as $row) {
            $value = $row["admin_db"];
                 if($value == 1){
                    return true;
                 } else {
                    return false;
                 }
             }
    }
}
```

***It happens here:***

> $value = $row["admin_db"];

Even when this error happens, the function is still returning a boolean value, which I require in another code.

I'm still new to PHP, and I don't know what this error means, or what am I doing wrong...

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you return what `var_dump($row);` outputs? (Put it above the `$row["admin_db"]` line).

Comment: This is the output when my function is called:
C:\wamp64\www\NewKali\includes\user.inc.php:55:string '1' (length=1)

Comment: Based on that output, I think that I'm getting an empty array, am I right?

Comment: I don't think so, it seems that `$row` is simply a string of `'1'`, I think you might be using the wrong method somewhere.

Comment: Well if the content of that var is '1', then that's exactly the value that I'm expecting, but I don't understand why it's deploying a warning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

```
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

I think your fetch is not returning an array indexed by column names but returns an array indexed by 0-indexed column number.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: This worked!
But I still don't know why tho, can you explaing why this worked?