# Error Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in

Tags: php, sql

I had to put PHP request on my site, but I got this error.

My error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\monsite\index.php on line 71
>   Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\monsite\index.php on line 71

My code:

```php
<?php
    //Connexion PDO
    try //afficher les erreurs de connection
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;bdname=bdd_site;charset=utf8','root','');
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
      die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    $contenu=$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM commentaire');
    //on affiche chaque entrée
    while($donnees=$contenu->fetch())
    {
        ?>
        <p> commentare de : <strong><?php  echo $donnees['Pseudo'];?></strong></p>
        <p> Note donnée par <strong> <?php echo $donnees['Pseudo'];?></strong> : <?php echo $donnees['Note']; ?></p>
        <p> comment :</p>
        <p style="color:red;"><?php echo $donnees['Comment'];?> </p>
    <?php
    }
    $contenu->closeCursor(); //termine traitemennt requête
?>
```

Comment: I think you will get more idea from here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696192/call-to-a-member-function-fetch-on-boolean

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This

```
      <?php
        //Connexion PDO
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=bdd_site;localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $password = '';
        //afficher les erreurs de connection
        try{
            $bdd = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
            $contenu = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM commentaire');
            //on affiche chaque entrée
            while ($donnees = $contenu->fetch()){
    ?>
            <p> commentare de : 
                <strong><?php echo $donnees['Pseudo']; ?></strong></p>
            <p> Note donnée par 
                <strong> <?php echo $donnees['Pseudo']; ?></strong> : <?php
                echo $donnees['Note']; ?></p>
            <p> comment :</p>
                <p style="color:red;"><?php echo $donnees['Comment']; ?> </p>
          <?php
            }
            $contenu->closeCursor(); //termine traitemennt requête

    ?>
```

Comment: What was the problem ?

Comment: The problem is PDO connection Syntax