# Displaying data from a database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I've been staring at code for hours trying to see what I'm missing.  Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

First I have a database with multiple tables.  One for images that stores the location and details of products.  I've built pages that let me view, edit and add products.  This all works great.

I'm now trying to do something simple and its not working.  I created a table "Contacts" in the database and added the rows "name, street, city, zip, phone, email".  I have populated this table with test data.

I'm trying to get my page to read the data and display it on the screen. I had wrote a complete page of html and screwed around with it trying to get it to work.  after getting frustrated I resorted to a very simple php script below.  I keep getting SQL error "Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\woody\Admin\index.php on line 38"   I know the first index is called "name" I have also attempted to replace "$results['name']" with "$results['0']" and "$results['1']".  Nothing seems to work. Anyone see what my tired eyes are missing?

```
<body>

<?php
    require_once("../includes/db.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM contact";
$query = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );        


echo htmlentities($results['name']);


?>








<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does return `var_dump($results)` ?

Comment: array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Where does `$conn` comes from ? Did you try to catch error when you defined it  ?

Comment: @scandel [you shouldn't catch](http://phpdelusions.net/delusion/try-catch)

Comment: my database connection php file:    <?php

try {
   
   $dbname = "database";
   $user = "site";
   $pass = "";
   $host = "localhost";


   # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
   // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }

catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo htmlentities($results[0]['name']);
```

would be correct way because you are using `fetchAll()` that returns a nested array.

or, more proper way as you are selecting many rows

```
foreach ($results as $row)
{
    echo htmlentities($row['name']);
}
```

If you want to select only one row, then you have to use `fetch()` method instead of `fetchAll()`. You may read about various fetch modes in the guide I wrote, [The only proper guide on PDO](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

If empty array is returned, than you **did not** populated the table with sample data

There is also a possibility for the error. You have to report them as described in [My PDO Statement doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/pdo-statement-returns-false)

Comment: Your right about the populate, as soon as I seen suggestion above I realized it did not populate.  So i populated the table using SQL statement in phpmyadmin and refreshed the page.  I got same sql error but now it shows the proper test data.....  I didn't use the foreach loop because there will only ever be one entry in the table.  Its the sellers contact info.  I want to make an admin age where they can edit the contact info that shows on the page instead of them directly messing with the HTML or server files.

Comment: you suggestion above worked,  Can you explain the difference between $results[0]['name']; and mine?

Comment: that's explained already. fetchAll() returns *nested* array. You may read about it by the link i added

Comment: You got it prefect,  Thanks for the help.  Going to go read your guide now!!