# pdo array how fetch all info from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to fetch all the info from a query , so I can use it for other purposes, the issue is that I'm just getting 1 result of each kind and I need them all, here is my script:

```
<?php
  require_once 'init.php';
  $base_datos = DB::getInstance();

  $base_datos->query ("SELECT lname, fname, category,user_id, SUM(points) as Point, SUM(amount)as Amount FROM request GROUP BY user_id");
   $get_info = $base_datos->results();
   $real_info = $get_info[0];
   $name = $real_info->lname;
   $last_name = $real_info->fname;
   $categories = $real_info->category;
   echo "$name";
   ///var_dump ($get_info);
  ?>
```

when echo $name all i get is one name i need to get them all and so on with the other value, when i do var_dump i got all i need, but i need to loop through,I'd searched all around and was not lucky.
[image]

this is what I'm trying to output on  php page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying data from a database using PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920889/displaying-data-from-a-database-using-pdo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `$get_info` is an array of objects based on how your code is currently written. Right now you're setting the first record of `$get_info` to `$real_info`.

So to access all of the records loop through `$get_info` like this.

```
foreach($get_info as $real_info) {
    echo $real_info->fname.' '.$real_info->lname;
}
```

Comment: exactly what i needed thanks, low reputation so i cant vote