# errorinfo function in pdo always return 0000 in medoo lib

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I use medoo mysql framework.

It works great and return error for all action like update/delete and...

But not for insert.

when I insert wrong data (or with wrong columns name), it returns 0 for last inserted id but also retrun 0000 for `$database->error()`!

this is some of my settings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and

```
'option' => [
        PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ]
```

how can I force it to show errors?

I use php7.0.10 and Ampps with mysql version 5.6.31/(localhost windows10)

Comment: You need to publish a full code example that shows how you implement the PDO db connection and options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/pdo-statement-returns-false

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the fact that *insert()* returns the last inserted ID. The medoo code looks like this:

```
$this->exec('INSERT INTO ' . $this->table_quote($table) . ' (' . implode(', ', $columns) . ') VALUES (' . implode($values, ', ') . ')');
$lastId[] = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
return count($lastId) > 1 ? $lastId : $lastId[0];
```

Now, if you would put this in between line 1 and 2:

```
var_dump($this->pdo->errorInfo());
```

You would get the error message from the INSERT command. The way medoo currently (Nov '16) handles this, you get the *lastInsertId()* error message, which is always 0000 (so no error).

**Two solutions**

1. For INSERTs you could use the *query()* method, build your own INSERT query and use *error()* as you usually would.
2. Or you could put the following in your config

   ```
   'option' => [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION],
   ```

and then always use *insert()* inside of try-catch:

```
try {
    $db->insert("table", ["column1" => "value1"]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Now you would get for example:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'value1' for key 'PRIMARY'