# SQL UPDATE on page change

Tags: php, html, sql, database, pdo

im using PDO SQL to connect, connection is success, but this..

```
<?php
include 'db.php'; // Call SQL
$page = 'soon'; // Unique ID
$db = "UPDATE views 
       SET num = num + 1 
       WHERE page = '$page'";
?>
```

does not work

If I check the values in the database, num is unchanged.

Comment: $db = "UPDATE views 
       SET num = num + 1 
       WHERE page = '".$page."'"; replace this query

Comment: UPDATE views 
       SET num = isnull(num,0) + 1 
       WHERE page = '$page'

Comment: What is $page and what is its value? You need to execute the query, but you need to make sure $page is properly initialized. If you can guarantee it will be numeric, then your query looks ok. If not, you need to make sure SQL injection is not possible in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This code is doing literally nothing. To have a query executed, you have to run it against a database. Besides, you should never ever add a variable directly to the query but only [through a parameter](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared):

```
<?php
include 'db.php'; // Call SQL
$page = 'soon'; // Unique ID
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE views SET num = num + 1 WHERE page = ?"); // instead of $page
$stmt->execute([$page]); // here goes $page
```

Comment: HTTP ERROR 500 :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/my-pdo-statement-doesnt-work

Comment: Instead of $db there should be a variable whereyou stored your PDO instance