# Query updating all records rather than record which matches input?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Apologies for vague title.
I currently have an edit form in which a product can be selected and the details are displayed in a form where they can be edited. Unfortunately, when edited every product in the product table is edited rather than just the product selected. To select the product i'm using where productname = productnameinput etc etc (Code below)

Database: http://prnt.sc/f4tf5g (Before an edit)

Tried adding the following WHERE statements at the end of the update query:

```
UPDATE product SET CategoryID = :newCatId,  ProductName = :newProdName, ProductDescription = :newProdDesc, stockCount = :newStock WHERE product.ProductName = :prodname

UPDATE product SET CategoryID = :newCatId,  ProductName = :newProdName, ProductDescription = :newProdDesc, stockCount = :newStock WHERE ProductName = :prodname
```

PHP:

```
// edit product in database
$query="
  SELECT * FROM category
";
$result = $DBH->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
$categories = $result->fetchAll();
//we need to select all products frist
$query3 = "
  SELECT * FROM product
";
$result3 = $DBH->prepare($query3);
$result3->execute();
$allProducts = $result3->fetchAll();

//When the Product is selected this function is run
  if (isset($_POST['choose'])) {
    $query2 = "
      SELECT product.*, category.* FROM product LEFT JOIN category ON category.CategoryID = product.CategoryID WHERE product.ProductName = :prodname
    ";
    $result2 = $DBH->prepare($query2);
    $result2->bindParam(':prodname', $_POST['product_name']);
    $result2->execute();
    $product = $result2->fetch();
  }
  //When the Update button is Pressed
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
      $query4 = "
        UPDATE product SET CategoryID = :newCatId,  ProductName = :newProdName, ProductDescription = :newProdDesc, stockCount = :newStock WHERE product.ProductName = :prodname
      ";
      $result4 = $DBH->prepare($query4);
      $result4->bindParam(':newCatId', $_POST['newcategory']);
      $result4->bindParam(':newProdName', $_POST['productName']);
      $result4->bindParam(':newProdDesc', $_POST['productDescription']);
      $result4->bindParam(':newStock', $_POST['stockCount']);
      $result4->bindParam(':prodname', $_POST['product_name']);

      $result4->execute();

    }
```

Comment: You need a `where` clause on the `update`.

Comment: Trying that now, thank you. Will update the question if unsuccessful but I think you're right

Comment: @chris85 Pretty sure you're right but i'm still getting errors, I have updated my question. Should I include $post product name etc?

Comment: What is the error, did you bind the new `where` column's value?

Comment: @chris85 I have yeah, and now no error appears but the info isn't being updated, I forgot to add the bind into the question, i'll add it now (this is using WHERE product.ProductName = :prodname)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php returns 0? It sounds like the name isn't matching, the `product.` shouldn't be needed. Do you have error reporting enabled, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32648423/4333555?

Comment: @chris85 Error reporting is enabled, and I also tried removing .product but same result. I've added the rowCount you suggested but 0 being edited.

Comment: Okay, so for some reason the value in the DB doesn't match the value you are passing. Try running just a `select` do you get results?

Comment: @chris85 I've got it working now after playing around with the binds for a while, would you like to submit an answer detailing adding the where statement so I can accept it

Comment: It seems like just a typo. I think you could just delete the question

Comment: @chris85 Ah I tried but it wont let me becuase it has two answers

Answer (score -1):

You are updating entire table, there is not filter in your update

```
$query4 = "
    UPDATE product SET CategoryID = :newCatId,  ProductName = :newProdName, ProductDescription = :newProdDesc, stockCount = :newStock
  ";
```