# PDO query not inserting and not throwing errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am inserting data into tables and also updating tables in my database using PDO which I am admittedly not the most knowledgeable about.

I am using a statement that I have used many times in the past, but for some reason this time it doesn't work for the prepared insert statement. It only worked for the update statement.

The statement is as follows:

```
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors',1); 
        //fetching error
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_beli (username, bank, norek, nama, ec, bitcoin, perfectmoney, fasapay, paket, saldo, amountbtc, phone, email, status, referer, iddb, date, ip, exp, unik,idph, upline, token) 
        VALUES(:username, :bank, :norek, :nama, :ec,  :bitcoin, :perfectmoney, :fasapay, :paket, :saldo, :amountbtc, :phone, :email, :status, :referer, :iddb, :date, :ip, :exp, :unik, :idph, :upline, :token)");
        $stmt ->execute(array(':username' => $kuriree, ':bank' => $bankee, ':norek' => $norekee, ':nama' => $namaee, ':ec' => $matauang,  ':bitcoin' => $bitcoinee, ':perfectmoney' => $pmee, ':fasapay' => $fasapayee, ':paket' => $paketzee, ':saldo' => $surabayae, ':amountbtc' => $convertbtc2, ':phone' => $phoneee, ':email' => $emailee, ':status' => $status1,':referer' => $kurirz,':iddb' => $idnyaz,':date' => $skrg,':ip' =>$laip ,':exp' => $exp,':unik' => $unikee,':idph' => $idnyaee,':upline' => $mangkosim,':token' => $unikeef ));
        //
        //echo  done  
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_jual (username, bank, norek, nama, ec,  bitcoin, perfectmoney, fasapay, paket, saldo, amountbtc, phone, email, status, date, ip, idgh, token) 
        VALUES(:username, :bank, :norek, :nama, :ec,  :bitcoin, :perfectmoney, :fasapay, :paket, :saldo, :amountbtc, :phone, :email, :status, :date, :ip, :idgh, :token)");
        $stmt ->execute(array(':username' => $kurirz, ':bank' => $bankeem, ':norek' => $norekeem, ':nama' => $namaeem, ':ec' => $matauang,  ':bitcoin' => $bitcoineem, ':perfectmoney' => $pmeem, ':fasapay' => $fasapayeem, ':paket' => $paketzee, ':saldo' => $surabayae, ':amountbtc' => $convertbtc2, ':phone' => $phoneeem, ':email' => $emaileem, ':status' => $status2, ':date' => $skrg, ':ip' => $laip, ':idgh' => $idnyaz, ':token' => $unikeef));
        //
        //echo  done  
        $stmt= $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tb_ph SET saldo= (saldo - :saldo) where id=:id ");
        $stmt ->execute(array(':id' => $idnyaee, ':saldo' => $surabayae)); 
        //
        //echo  done  
        $stmt= $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tb_gh SET saldo= (saldo - :saldo) where id=:id");
        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $idnyaz , ':saldo' => $surabayae));
        //echo  done  
        //array ends here for checkup
```

But unfortunately this is always returning to be `TRUE` without any data to the database tables. only updating, which was supposed to be done after the insertion  into my database.

I have tried every combination changes to the statement that I could think of, but I am still at a loss. Also it doesn't return any error.

Comment: on the interweb caps = shouting

Comment: You don't don't actually check for errors

Comment: Both inserts fail?

Comment: So the problem is the `INSERT` queries right?

Comment: @swellar Yes. The update queries worked perfectly.

Comment: To add to @JohnConde you need to tell PDO to give you errors, the error reporting you are currently displaying is for PHP errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/my-pdo-statement-doesnt-work

Comment: Check the return value of `execute()` if it is `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: you are overriding the `$stmt` variable

Comment: i have tried the insert with a diferent variable, still no result

Comment: @LegiSmith can you try my answer below

Comment: tried it on a normal query and it worked.

Comment: let me set it up for the condition and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the Colon(:) in Execute statement as follows,

Following code worked for me ( added test values).

```
$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_beli(username, bank, norek, nama, ec, bitcoin, perfectmoney, fasapay, paket, saldo, amountbtc, phone, email, status, referer, iddb, date, ip, exp, unik,idph, upline, token)
VALUES(:username, :bank, :norek, :nama, :ec,  :bitcoin, :perfectmoney, :fasapay, :paket, :saldo, :amountbtc, :phone, :email, :status, :referer, :iddb, :date, :ip, :exp, :unik, :idph, :upline, :token)");

$kuriree = 'bb';
$bankee  = 'cc'; 
$norekee  = 'cc'; 
$namaee  = 'cc'; 
$matauang  = 'cc';  
$bitcoinee  = 'cc';
$pmee  = 'cc';
$fasapayee  = 'cc';
$paketzee  = 'cc'; 
$surabayae  = 'cc'; 
$convertbtc2  = 'cc';
$phoneee  = 'cc';
$emailee  = 'cc'; 
$status1  = 'cc';
$kurirz  = 'cc';
$idnyaz  = 'cc';
$skrg  = 'cc';
$laip   = 'cc';
$exp  = 'cc';
$unikee  = 'cc';
$idnyaee  = 'cc';
$mangkosim  = 'cc';
$unikeef   = 'aa';

$ret = $statement->execute(array('username' => $kuriree, 'bank' => $bankee, 'norek' => $norekee, 'nama' => $namaee, 'ec' => $matauang,  'bitcoin' => $bitcoinee, 'perfectmoney' => $pmee, 'fasapay' => $fasapayee, 'paket' => $paketzee, 'saldo' => $surabayae, 'amountbtc' => $convertbtc2, 'phone' => $phoneee, 'email' => $emailee, 'status' => $status1,'referer' => $kurirz,'iddb' => $idnyaz,'date' => $skrg,'ip' =>$laip ,'exp' => $exp,'unik' => $unikee,'idph' => $idnyaee,'upline' => $mangkosim,'token' => $unikeef ));

if($ret)
    print '1 row Inserted';
else
    print 'Error in Inserting';
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But there was still no solution. only the aspect of update works perfectly.

Comment: Is Insert not working ? (have you you given id as Primary key and set for auto increment?)

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are overriding the `$stmt` variable every-time therefore only one `$stmt` will work, the last one which is update might work.

try this might be what you looking for :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {

    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    //fetching error
    if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_beli (username, bank, norek, nama, ec, bitcoin, perfectmoney, fasapay, paket, saldo, amountbtc, phone, email, status, referer, iddb, date, ip, exp, unik,idph, upline, token) 
        VALUES(:username, :bank, :norek, :nama, :ec,  :bitcoin, :perfectmoney, :fasapay, :paket, :saldo, :amountbtc, :phone, :email, :status, :referer, :iddb, :date, :ip, :exp, :unik, :idph, :upline, :token)")) {

        if (!$stmt->execute(array(
            ':username' => $kuriree,
            ':bank' => $bankee,
            ':norek' => $norekee,
            ':nama' => $namaee,
            ':ec' => $matauang,
            ':bitcoin' => $bitcoinee,
            ':perfectmoney' => $pmee,
            ':fasapay' => $fasapayee,
            ':paket' => $paketzee,
            ':saldo' => $surabayae,
            ':amountbtc' => $convertbtc2,
            ':phone' => $phoneee,
            ':email' => $emailee,
            ':status' => $status1,
            ':referer' => $kurirz,
            ':iddb' => $idnyaz,
            ':date' => $skrg,
            ':ip' => $laip,
            ':exp' => $exp,
            ':unik' => $unikee,
            ':idph' => $idnyaee,
            ':upline' => $mangkosim,
            ':token' => $unikeef
        ))) {


            $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception($error);
        }

        if ($stmt_two = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_jual (username, bank, norek, nama, ec,  bitcoin, perfectmoney, fasapay, paket, saldo, amountbtc, phone, email, status, date, ip, idgh, token) 
        VALUES(:username, :bank, :norek, :nama, :ec,  :bitcoin, :perfectmoney, :fasapay, :paket, :saldo, :amountbtc, :phone, :email, :status, :date, :ip, :idgh, :token)")) {

            if (!$stmt_two->execute(array(
                ':username' => $kurirz,
                ':bank' => $bankeem,
                ':norek' => $norekeem,
                ':nama' => $namaeem,
                ':ec' => $matauang,
                ':bitcoin' => $bitcoineem,
                ':perfectmoney' => $pmeem,
                ':fasapay' => $fasapayeem,
                ':paket' => $paketzee,
                ':saldo' => $surabayae,
                ':amountbtc' => $convertbtc2,
                ':phone' => $phoneeem,
                ':email' => $emaileem,
                ':status' => $status2,
                ':date' => $skrg,
                ':ip' => $laip,
                ':idgh' => $idnyaz,
                ':token' => $unikeef
            ))) {


                throw new Exception($stmt_two->errorInfo());
            }
        }

        if ($stmt_three = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tb_ph SET saldo= (saldo - :saldo) where id=:id ")) {

            if (!$stmt_three->execute(array(
                ':id' => $idnyaee,
                ':saldo' => $surabayae
            ))) {

                throw new Exception($stmt_three->errorInfo());
            }
        }

        if ($stmt_four->$pdo->prepare("UPDATE tb_gh SET saldo= (saldo - :saldo) where id=:id")) {

            if (!$stmt_four->execute(array(
                ':id' => $idnyaz,
                ':saldo' => $surabayae
            ))) {

                throw new Exception($stmt_four->errorInfo());
            }
        }

    }

    if ($pdo->commit()) {
        echo "Data Proccessing complete";
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Transaction commit failed.');
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    try {
        // something went wrong, we have to rollback
        $pdo->rollback();
        // and display the error message
        echo "error : " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    catch (Exception $f) {
        // and display the error message
        echo "error" . $f->getMessage();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: tried this but now dispaying a blank screen even when error reporting was on