# Populating mysql table with json data in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I have the following example json file and I'm trying to populate a MySQL table with it. Populating books table with json data did not work and with no errors. I want to know what is wrong in the following PHP code:

```
    <?php
$connect=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=books','root','0000');
$filename= "data.json";
$data=file_get_contents($filename);
$array=json_decode($data,true);
$stmt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO books values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
foreach($array["books"] as $row){

$stmt->bindParam(1,$row['isbn']);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$row['title']);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$row['subtitle']);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$row['author']);
$stmt->bindParam(5,$row['published']);
$stmt->bindParam(6,$row['publisher']);
$stmt->bindParam(7,$row['pages']);
$stmt->bindParam(8,$row['description']);
$stmt->bindParam(9,$row['website']);
$stmt->execute();
}

?>
```

json file looks like this:

```
 {
   "books":[
      {
         "isbn":"9781593275846",
         "title":"Eloquent JavaScript, Second Edition",
         "subtitle":"A Modern Introduction to Programming",
         "author":"Marijn Haverbeke",
         "published":"2014-12-14T00:00:00.000Z",
         "publisher":"No Starch Press",
         "pages":472,
         "description":"JavaScript lies at the heart of almost every modern web application, from social apps to the newest browser-based games. Though simple for beginners to pick up and play with, JavaScript is a flexible, complex language that you can use to build full-scale applications.",
         "website":"http://eloquentjavascript.net/"
      },
      {
         "isbn":"9781449331818",
         "title":"Learning JavaScript Design Patterns",
         "subtitle":"A JavaScript and jQuery Developer's Guide",
         "author":"Addy Osmani",
         "published":"2012-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
         "publisher":"O'Reilly Media",
         "pages":254,
         "description":"With Learning JavaScript Design Patterns, you'll learn how to write beautiful, structured, and maintainable JavaScript by applying classical and modern design patterns to the language. If you want to keep your code efficient, more manageable, and up-to-date with the latest best practices, this book is for you.",
         "website":"http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/"
      } ] }
```

Mysql table structure looks like this:

```
--- Table structure for table `books`
--

CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `isbn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `subtitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `published` date NOT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `pages` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lGql.png)

Comment: $stmt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO books (add coloum here) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

Comment: I added the column names like this: $stmt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO books (isbn,title,subtitle,author,published,publisher,pages,description,website) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); still the data not inserted

Comment: can you show what are the errors ?

Comment: There are no errors but when I go to phpmyadmin to check if the data inserted, I found that no any data inserted!

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $row['isbn'],$row['title'],$row['subtitle'],$row['author'],$row['published'],$row['publisher'],$row['pages'],$row['description'],$row['website']);

Comment: @sandra Can you output PDO errors please? please check this question on how to get them to display https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/my-pdo-statement-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some error reporting to see what if there is an error and also first bind the variables and then set them in foreach loop and execute the query

```
try {
$connect=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=books','root','0000');
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO books (isbn,title,subtitle,author,published,publisher,pages,description,website) values(:isbn,:title,:subtitle,:author,:published,:publisher,:pages,:description,:website)");
$filename= "data.json";
$data=file_get_contents($filename);
$array=json_decode($data,true);
$stmt->bindParam(':isbn', $isbn);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':subtitle', $subtitle);
$stmt->bindParam(':author', $author);
$stmt->bindParam(':published', $published);
$stmt->bindParam(':publisher', $publisher);
$stmt->bindParam(':pages', $pages);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
$stmt->bindParam(':website', $website);
foreach($array["books"] as $row){
    $isbn = $row['isbn'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $subtitle = $row['subtitle'];
    $author = $row['author'];
    $published = $row['published'];
    $publisher = $row['publisher'];
    $pages = $row['pages'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $website = $row['website'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I updated the code according to your answer I got no errors but no data inserted into books table

Comment: @sandar is using correct syntax for PDO, please check example 2 http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Don't just say "try this" with a massive code dump. I'll remove my downvote but **please** add more detail on what you have changed and why you have added/made that change

Comment: I got the following error:   Error: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'isbn' at row 1

Comment: @WillParky93 you are right i added some text to clarify what i did

Comment: @Sandra it is because you have isbn int(11) but the value you are trying to pass is int(13) you have to change your database to be able to store a bigger value in isbn

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou I edited the database isbn int(15) nothing worked and I got the same error

Comment: @Sandra change it to float(15) or bigint(15)

Comment: @sandra I think you'll be better storing the ISBN as a varchar instead of an integer. You're not doing any calculations on it and it'll be able to handle the large number.

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou Now the error is Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '2014-12-14T00:00:00.000Z' for column 'published' at row 1

Comment: @WillParky93 Ok I will do

Comment: @sandra issue with latest can be solved with removing the T and Z from your input data.  `$published = str_replace('T','',$published); $published = str_replace('Z',$published);` before inserting `$published` into your database. There's probably a cleaner way to do this but I can't test right now

Comment: @Sandra also you should propably change published from date type to datetime type

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou Thank you very much, the problem solved, the code and the data type was incorrect in my table structure.

Comment: @Sandra Glad to help you :)

Comment: @WillParky93 Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling on this there's a small error in Dimitris' code above  and the edit queue is full.

The 'try' block is opened but not closed so I added a closing brace:

```
try {
$connect=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=books','root','0000');
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO books (isbn,title,subtitle,author,published,publisher,pages,description,website) values(:isbn,:title,:subtitle,:author,:published,:publisher,:pages,:description,:website)");
$filename= "data.json";
$data=file_get_contents($filename);
$array=json_decode($data,true);
$stmt->bindParam(':isbn', $isbn);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':subtitle', $subtitle);
$stmt->bindParam(':author', $author);
$stmt->bindParam(':published', $published);
$stmt->bindParam(':publisher', $publisher);
$stmt->bindParam(':pages', $pages);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
$stmt->bindParam(':website', $website);
foreach($array["books"] as $row){
    $isbn = $row['isbn'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $subtitle = $row['subtitle'];
    $author = $row['author'];
    $published = $row['published'];
    $publisher = $row['publisher'];
    $pages = $row['pages'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $website = $row['website'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
} // Added this brace to close the 'try' opening brace
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```