# PDO union select results nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to select `name`, `surname` from `users` where `username` = column `following` inside `network_follow` table

the query:

```
"SELECT * FROM network_follow WHERE following = :f UNION SELECT name, surname FROM users where username = (following)";
```

php code:

```
 $f = $conexao_pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM network_follow WHERE following = :f UNION SELECT name, surname FROM users where username = (following)');
    $f->bindParam(':f', $db_user);
    $f->execute();

    while($values = $f->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $fvalue = $values['follower'];
        $fname = $values['name'];
        echo '<center> 
    <div><a href=""> <img class="rounded-circle"  width="45" src="'.get_user_picture($fvalue).'"></img>&nbsp;@'.$fvalue.'</a>
     <span style="padding-left: 15px;">'.$fname.'<span>
     <div></center>';

}
```

Resulting to me `$fvalue` just fine, but not `$fname`

for some reasons **union select** is not working, can somebody help?

Comment: Doing a union with `*` on one SELECT and `name, surname` on the other doesn't seem right. What do these tables look like? Have you attempted to run this query outside of PHP?

Comment: I think what you actually want is a `JOIN` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: table `network_follow` have column `following` , `follower`  , table `users` have `name`, `surname`, `username` columns

Comment: @Developer so how exactly does `following` match up with `name` for example? Seems likely @rickdenhaan is right that you don't actually want a UNION at all.

Comment: how to implement a join in this case?

Comment: Something along the lines of `SELECT nf.*, u.name, u.surname FROM network_follow nf INNER JOIN users u ON u.username = nf.following WHERE nf.following = :f`? Though if `following` is really the string username, you might want to normalise your schema a bit more.

Comment: I don't have name, surname inside `network_follow` table, only following/followers,  the columns username, name, surname is inside `users` table

Comment: @Jonnix  you my friend

Comment: Then your comment doesn't make sense. My guess is you don't know about SQL aliases, but you should look those up yourself along with joins.

Comment: should I also add users table inside my `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` ? because when I echo  `$fname = $values['name']´ it shows noting on name but shows `follower`just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UNION` is used to *select similar* data from multiple tables.

A `JOIN` is used to *combine related* data from multiple tables.

Examples:

```
SELECT `city`, `sights` FROM `places_i_visited`
UNION
SELECT `city`, `sights` FROM `places_i_want_to_visit`

+----------------+--------+
| city           | sights |
+================+========+
| Los Angeles    | 1537   |  -- from `places_i_visited`
| Rio de Janeiro | 829    |  -- from `places_i_visited`
| Moscow         | 1822   |  -- from `places_i_want_to_visit`
+----------------+--------+

SELECT `city`, `sights`, `visits`.`date_visited`, `visits`.`duration`, `visits`.`sights_seen` FROM `places_i_visited`
INNER JOIN `visits` ON `visits`.`city_id` = `places_i_visited`.`city_id`

+----------------+--------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| city           | sights | date_visited | duration | sights_seen |
+================+========+==============+==========+=============+
| Los Angeles    | 1537   | 2017-06-25   | 14       | 25          |
| Rio de Janeiro | 829    | 2018-11-04   | 7        | 12          |
+----------------+--------+--------------+----------+-------------+
```

In your case, you want to take information from your `network_following` table and *combine it* with the user's name from the `users` table. A `JOIN` is more appropriate here:

```
SELECT network_follow.*, users.name, users.surname FROM network_follow
INNER JOIN users ON users.username = network_follow.following
WHERE following = :f
```

I'm using an `INNER JOIN` here to make sure you *only* see entries that have results in both tables.

If you want to see if you have inconsistent data in your database, you could use a `LEFT JOIN` instead. That way, you'll see *all* entries from the `network_follow` table. If there is no such user in the `users` table, you will still see those entries but the `name` and `surname` columns will be `NULL`.

Comment: I don't have  `name`, `surname` inside `network_follow` table, only following/followers, the columns `username`, `name`, `surname` is inside users table , the where clause is username  = following column, for some reasons your code retuns blank

Comment: My code is explicitly selecting those columns from the `users` table. If you're getting a blank result, `var_dump($f); die();` immediately after `$f = $conexado_pdo->prepare(...);`. If that outputs `bool(false)` make sure [you can see any errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32648423/1941241) and tell us what's wrong.

Comment: does it's right? it works fine but whan I echo `$fname = $values['name'];` nothing show

Comment: var dump shows `object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(155) "SELECT network_follow.*, users.name, users.surname FROM network_follow INNER JOIN users ON users.username = network_follow.following WHERE following = :f" }`

Comment: Then the query is executing fine but your database may not contain what you think it does. Are there any matching rows at all (`var_dump($f->rowCount());`)? If not, you need to check the value of `$db_user` against what's actually in your database. If there are matching rows, `print_r($values);` to see what each row contains.

Comment: running `print_r($values);` I get this `( [following] => user1 [follower] => user2 [name] => [surname] => )` but both users are in db value, maybe something in the query is not selecting

Comment: At this point, it's impossible to say without looking at your database. If you're using an `INNER JOIN`, this can only happen if `users` contains a user with `username = 'user1'` where `name` and `surname` are empty. If you're using a `LEFT JOIN`, this can mean the same thing or that `users` does not contain a user with `username = 'user1'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query instead of use `UNION` statement:

```
SELECT t1.*
    ,t2.name
    ,t2.surname
FROM network_follow AS t1
INNER JOIN users AS t2 ON t1.following = t2.username
WHERE t2.following = ':f'
```

Although you need to think about any ID's columns, Primary and Foreign keys to normalize a bit your tables.

Comment: when I echo `$fname = $values['name']´ it shows nothing but the query is executed, I changed to `SELECT t1.*
    ,t2.name
    ,t2.surname
FROM network_follow AS t1
INNER JOIN users AS t2 ON t1.following = t2.username
WHERE t1.following = :f'`