# Code does not work on web hosting but works on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, select

The code works fine locally but fails online:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchColumn()
>   on boolean in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx/yyyy/index.php:30 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/yyyy/index.php....

```
@$eu = ($start - 0); 
$limit = 24;          
$this1 = $eu + $limit; 
$back = $eu - $limit; 
$next = $eu + $limit; 
$pro = $next + 1; 
$ant = $back + 1; 

$query=" select distinct(me_image.gal_id),file_name, gallery,img_id  from me_image,  me_gallery where me_image.gal_id=me_gallery.gal_id group by me_image.gal_id order by gal_id desc limit $eu, $limit";

$query2=" select distinct(me_image.gal_id),file_name, gallery,img_id  from me_image,  me_gallery where me_image.gal_id=me_gallery.gal_id group by me_image.gal_id order by gal_id ";

$nume = $dbo->query("$query2")->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Your query failed. Break that call chain apart, check the status, and check the error message.

Comment: `$dbo->query("$query2")` is returning a `false` (the boolean value) not an object. Check the SQL, make sure table and database and column names are all correct, etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My PDO Statement doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/my-pdo-statement-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Export the db from local and import it to the remote (to be sure they the same), make sure to change the connection settings to db on remote code.

Check php and mysql version on local and remote, in case they are the same, and the above steps are done, yet you get the error, most probably you missing some php configurations on the remote.