# Having issue with matching rows in the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am looking to get row count to check if same email is already in database or not. i have tried couple of mechanism but no success. when i run my query directly in the database it gives me the row count but via PDO execute it gives me 0.

i have used fetchAll method to manually count, even used rowCount method that also not working

```
$sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM inbox WHERE uid = ? AND from_email = ?'; 
$result = $link->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute([$email_number,$email_f]); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

issue is with this $email_f, it contains html

```
SELECT count(*) FROM inbox WHERE uid = "6961" 
AND from_email = "abc Offers <abc@abcs.com>"
```

this is the query which i have printed from $sql and when i execute it in database directly in phpmyadmin, it works fine. give me count of 3 but via execute i get 0.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: i am getting no data in fetch when executing the PDO->execute; but if i run my printed query in phpmyadmin it gives me the output of 3 rows.

Comment: Okay, I'll post an answer which is given as an example in PHP.net site. Let's see how it works.

Comment: Do you have other queries in this same application that are returning the data as expected in your php file?

Also, when you tried running the query directly in phpMyAdmin, did you copy and paste the output from the $sql variable or did you re-type it manually? If the contents of $email_f is expected to be HTML, is it possible that you have an encoding issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you have to embrace the fact: if your query found no rows,  it means there is *no* match, even if you can swear the data is all right. When the query returns no rows, then there are no rows to match the condition. So you have to find out - why. But first of all you need to make sure that your query is all right:

#### Problems caused by SQL errors

First of all you need to make sure that your query actually runs without errors as "no result" could mean an error in the query. Refer to these answers for the details: [pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32648423/285587) and [mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/what-to-do-with-mysqli-problems-errors-like-mysqli-fetch-array-argument-1-m).

In case the error says "no such table/database", see the "connection credentials" case below.

### Problems caused by the condition

Check your conditions. There are mutual exclusive conditions, such as `WHERE col=1 AND col=2`. It will never return any rows. Try to simplify the condition until it starts returning some rows, and then refine the conditions to get the desired result.

---

But all right, there are no errors, conditions are correct, and you can swear there is data in the table to match your query. Still, there are some pitfalls:

### Problems caused by the data

First of all, in case a variable involved, make sure it *exists* and actually contains some value.

Then check the value itself. There could be some converted or non-printable characters in the input data (or database). For example a linefeed character or a peculiarly encoded symbol, or some characters such as `<` and `>` converted into HTML entities. As a result, the query contains `<abc@abcs.com>` will never match a text `&lt;abc@abcs.com&gt;`. For a quick check you can use `rawurlencode()` function, it will convert all non-latin characters into codes, thus making them visible.

The problem is, this is only a guess, and nobody can tell you what the actual issue is, because it is **your** database, **your** input data and only **you** can find the issue.

I wrote an article that explains [how to debug your PDO issues](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve).

To debug a particular issue, you need

- make sure the full error reporting is enabled for both PDO and PHP. It really helps, showing you occasional typographic errors, spelling errors and the such
- scrutinize both the data in the database and the input to find the difference. `urlencode()` function would help, revealing all non-printable and converted characters, in both database and the input.

### Problems caused by the connection credentials

Another frequent issue is when you have several databases and connect to the wrong one that doesn't have the data requested. This issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665821/mysql-couldnt-connect-unknown-database-databasename-error), so just follow the same routine, only checking not the list of tables but the data rows.

### Problems caused by character set/encoding

It's a rare case, but just to to be sure, follow the checklist from this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/285587)

Comment: i have sorted out the issue myself and the issue was same what you explained above, i was converting some characters such as < and > into HTML entities. i removed that part and it worked. regarding the code i understand the way you have mentioned, it should be like that. i did changed it to my way because i wanted to print the query with values to test it directly in database as well.