# PHP Prepared Statement not inserting, no errors appearing

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am attempting to insert some data via prepared statements in PHP.  I have the following code which is not inserting for me.  I also have the following code set already

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

error_reporting(~0);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

try {
    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO deck_cards (deckid, cardid, qty) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $stmtInsert = $conn->prepare($sqlInsert);
    
    if ($stmtInsert)
    {
        $stmtInsert->bind_param("sss", $deckid, $cardid, $cardcount) or trigger_error($stmtInsert->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        $stmtInsert->execute() or trigger_error($stmtInsert->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        echo "Check if this ran";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        $conn->close();
    }

    $stmtInsert->close();
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo 'Exception occurred '.$ex->getTraceAsString();
}
```

When this executes, I do see the text "Check if this ran" but no other messages.  The data is not inserted into the database.  Additionally, I echo'd the SQL string and variables and ran it against the MySQL directly and it inserted OK.  Not sure what is happening in my very straightforward code above.

Additionally, inserts are happening OK in other pages within my app, but this page for some reason isn't working.

I know it's overkill on my error reporting, but I threw everything I could think of to see if there is an error somewhere, but this one is a head scratcher for me.  Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Are you sure all three parameters are strings? The variable names look more like "iii", because you have two IDs and a counter. What's the datatype of your DB fields?

Comment: This overkill error handling might actually be hiding the proper error from you. You should remove all of it and only keep 3 lines: prepare, bind and execute.

Comment: @Aranxo All are ints, in the example I am trying to run its 2, 56, 4

Comment: There are no errors in your code. It looks correct, aside from all this extraneous error checking.

Comment: @Dharman, ya that's what I figured too, I've been banging my head on this all morning, seems straightforward, maybe I will try without prepared statement as a test and see what happens

Comment: No, the prepared statement is not an issue. You must use PS and you are doing it correctly. If there's an error, it's not in this piece of code.

Comment: So why don't you try `$stmtInsert->bind_param("iii", $deckid, $cardid, $cardcount)`?

Comment: @Aranxo just tried that, same result unfortunately

Comment: @Aranxo All strings can be ints. It's highly unlikely that sending ints as string would cause any issue. Sending data as strings is the safest option.

Comment: I just tried this, it echo'd the success message, nothing saved, I copied the string and pasted into phpmyadmin and it executed ok....SIGH $sql = "INSERT INTO deck_cards (deckid, cardid, qty) VALUES (" . $deckid . "," . $cardid . "," . $cardcount . ")";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "New record created successfully";
                  } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                  }

Comment: I also added echo $stmtInsert->affected_rows;  It is showing 1, but nothing in DB argh

Comment: I just wanted to give the hint $stmtInsert->affected_rows, but you already did it. Is there an option, that prevents prepared statements in the DB? Is there some caching mechanism, so that the new record is hanging in the cache? Just brainstorming...

Comment: It's more likely that your PHP is connected to a different mysql/mariadb instance than your phpmyadmin. This is the case more often than not that I've seen in questions where the PHP code appears to work, but nothing is visible in the admin tool. Have you tried writing some code in PHP to SELECT from that table immediately afterwards, and fetch all the rows and display them? Does that produce the data you're expecting?

Answer (score 1):

In case your query seemingly doesn't work, it can be caused by following reasons:

- **The SQL didn't run at all,** due to incorrect program logic. Add temporary debugging output to as much places as possible (or use the step debugging feature in your editor) to follow the program's logic and to make sure that the code actually reached the point where the query must be executed.
- **There was an error during query execution**. Check these answers for the detailed explanation on how to configure proper error reporting for [mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/285587) or [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32648423/285587).

Hence your code should be like this (given the top three lines should be moved into some bootstrap file that you'd include here)

```php
echo "Start\n"; // debugging statement, remove after resolving the issue

$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO deck_cards (deckid, cardid, qty) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmtInsert = $conn->prepare($sqlInsert);
$stmtInsert->bind_param("sss", $deckid, $cardid, $cardcount);

echo "INSERT done\n"; // debugging statement, remove after resolving the issue
```

In case the query was actually executed, and there was no errors, it means that query was *successful.* It you still cannot observe the desired result:

- For a SELECT query that just doesn't return expected values, it's definitely input data doesn't match that in the database. Here are some recommendations on [how to debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57986043/285587)
- in case it's INSERT (or other data modification query), then it's possible that the result is viewed in the [wrong database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60666640/285587). To get a proof, print out the result of `insert_id`/`affected_rows` and/or result of `mysqli_info()`. You can also select the inserted data and print it out right here, immediately below the INSERT. Then double check database credentials for the program which you are using to see the results.
- There is an open transaction or autocommit set to 0 somewhere in the code, but no explicit commit. Check your code and either remove `begin` or add `commit`.