# PDO error: $pdo->prepare()->execute() throws err "Call to a member function fetch() on boolean"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If my pdo query like:

```
$sql=$pdo->prepare('select timezone from wo_users where user_id=?')->execute(array($wo['user']['user_id']));
while($row=$sql->fetch()){var_dump($row);die;}
```

Will throw an error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   fetch() on boolean in
>   C:\wamp64\www\community.voyance\2\sources\calendar.php on line 27

But if my pdo query that uses query() directly will not throw error:

```
$sql=$pdo->query('select timezone from wo_users where user_id=1;');
while($row=$sql->fetch()){var_dump($row);die;}
```

> C:\wamp64\www\community.voyance\2\sources\calendar.php:27: array
>   (size=1)   'timezone' => string '-8' (length=2)

Why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: [A simple helper function/class](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#function) to overcome the nuisance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `PDOStatement` to fetch, `execute` only returns true or false. You should only `execute` the `PDOStatement`. That will give you back a result object you can `fetch` or an error. For PDO error handling see [My PDO Statement doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/my-pdo-statement-doesnt-work).

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select timezone from wo_users where user_id=?');
$stmt->execute(array($wo['user']['user_id']));
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     var_dump($row);
     die;
}
```

As you can see from the manual [query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) works because:

> PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

where as [execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

the [`prepare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) is what we need:

> If the database server successfully prepares the statement, PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

and [fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) (this one is the description, not the return):

> Fetches a row from a result set associated with a PDOStatement object

Comment: $sql = $pdo->prepare('select timezone from wo_users where user_id=?');$sql->execute(array($wo['user']['user_id']));

Comment: See the longer write up. It has to do with what each function call returns.