# How do I create a row in sql PDO php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

//Here is my attempt:

```
<?php
//PDO prepare statement to create a row in the database'

$pdo = new PDO("sqlite:customer.db");

$statement = 
$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO customer(CustomerID, CustomerName) VALUES('LA002', 'Alex Matrix')");
$statement->execute();
$numberOfRowsCreated = $statement->rowCount();
echo "Created ".$numberOfRowsCreated." new rows";
```

//I get 0 new rows. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello Irene. Your question is rather not "How do I create  a new row" (which you already know), but "why it doesn't insert a new row?". It doesn't insert because there is an error. You need to get the error message and fix it. Refer to this answer for how to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32648423/285587

Comment: I read your post  and the few other ones before posting the question. I figured it out. The code was correct, the database was the problem. It's working now.