# Why my queries with bind param do not work?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want in my file execute 3 query at once, my code looks like this:

```
$stmtinsertcustomers = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO customers (id, name, phone)
VALUES ('', ?, ?)");
echo $conn->error;
$stmtinsertcustomers->bind_param("ss", $name, $phone);
$stmtinsertcustomers->execute();
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
$stmtinsertcustomers->close();


$stmtinsertorder = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (customerid, orderid, orderdate) VALUES (?,?,?)");
echo $conn->error;
$stmtinsertorder->bind_param("sss", $last_id, $orderid, $date);
$stmtinsertorder->execute();
$stmtinsertorder->close();

$stmtinsertorderitems = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orderitems (orderid, productid) VALUES (?,?)");
echo $conn->error;
$stmtinsertorderitems->bind_param("ss", $orderid, $productid);
$stmtinsertorderitems->execute();
$stmtinsertorderitems->close();
```

But it's unfortunately not working, what is the problem? Thank you for helping!

Comment: Firstly it's worth knowing which API you are using, PDO and mysqli have different methods and you access them in slightly different ways.  You say you are using PDO, but call `mysqli_insert_id()` and `bind_param()`.

Comment: I dont use any API, yes you're right, I need to use $last_id = $stmtinsertcustomers->lastInsertId(); if I understand correctly

Comment: PDO and mysqli are both API's for using a database.  You can't mix the calls between the 2 different API's and so you need to first ensure you know which you are using.

Comment: I want to use PDO rather because of SQL injuries, but thanks good to know. But why theese multiple inserts not working?

Comment: you can prevent `sql injuries` (lol) with `mysqli` just as with `PDO`...

Comment: OMG sorry injections

Comment: At what point do the above queries fail? Does the first `insert` correctly return the `insert_id` value? Do any records get inserted?

Comment: Also - it might be worth looking into [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) - you could easily replace the last statement with a trigger

Comment: Here's how you can check for the [actual mysqli error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param/22662582#22662582) and here's how to do the same for [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/my-pdo-statement-doesnt-work/32648423#32648423).

Comment: The first one is not inserting nothing but last 2 one working perfectly

Comment: Side note: you can skip the id in the insert statement if it's auto incremental.

Comment: It's impossible. There is always either a successful insert or an error. The `''` is improper value for a numeric field that may cause an error