# INSERT INTO instrction is not working (sql & php)?

Tags: php, html, sql

i am trying to insert a line in my table (link,class,username,title,subject)

```
$req = $bdd -> prepare('INSERT INTO videos (lien,classe,user,titre,matiere) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');
             $req -> execute(array($lien,$classe,$user,$titre,$matiere));
```

everything is an html input except user is a variable that already exist :

```
$matiere = isset($_POST['matiere']) ? $_POST['matiere'] : "";
          $classe = isset($_POST['classe']) ? $_POST['classe'] : "";
          $lien = isset($_POST['lien']) ? $_POST['lien'] : "";
          $titre = isset($_POST['titre']) ? $_POST['titre'] : "";
          $user = isset ($_SESSION['nom']) ? $_SESSION['nom'] : "";
```

but there is no line added in my table,btw when i remove $user everything work fine ,and i dont know what i am doing wrong here ,(i am a beginner in sql & php)

Comment: What are you using to access the DB? PDO or MYSQLi?

Comment: Is it `username` or `user` in db? Use error reporting to see what it says the error is. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/my-pdo-statement-doesnt-work if unfamiliar with how to get errors with PDO.