# PHP/PDO/MariaDB: Trying to pull a single value based on a session "user_id" and print the result

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

I'm a noob at PHP and am attempting to run a query using PDO to pull a single value based on a "user_id" value that is a part of the login session.  There is a user_type column that indicates user or admin.  I can't get the $user_type to echo on the page but I can get the $user_id to echo.

It doesn't error out.  I'm pretty stumped on it and am hoping for some help.

```
    $user_query = "SELECT user_type FROM users WHERE 'user_id' = '".$user_id."'";
    $stmt = $pdo->query($user_query);

    if ($stmt === false) {
        die("Error executing the query.");
    }

    else $user_type = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    echo $user_type; echo $user_id;
```

Comment: `var_dump($user_type)` gives what? You should use prepared statements and parameterized queries.

Comment: `WHERE 'user_id' =` should be `WHERE user_id =` or `user_id` encapsulated in backticks. Single quotes are for strings, not identifiers.

Comment: Look at using something like https://3v4l.org/bfHX0.

Comment: @user3783243 couple suggestions, if you let me. You can have this code actually running with [phpize.online](https://phpize.online/). You should [never ever do anything like](https://phpdelusions.net/basic_principles_of_web_programming#error_reporting) `die("Error")`. Not to mention that `if ($stmt === false)` makes no sense anyway. Pay attention to the code provided, it is using fetchColumn() instead of fetch().

Comment: @BrandonWaggoner, it looks like you are using a really bad tutorial that makes you write weird and bizarre code. Consider looking at the [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) I wrote (and the [practical examples section](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples) as well)

Comment: @BrandonWaggoner, regarding your current struggle, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/why-does-this-pdo-statement-silently-fail)