Why the error message "Call to a member function execute()" is not suppressed in try-catch?
I have the code:
try {
    $db = new PDO("sqlite:filename.db");
    $q = $db->prepare("SELECT p1 FROM T1;");
    $q->execute(); // Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Process any database errors in one place
}

The file "filename.db" does not exist at the moment.
I would like to process all DB errors in one place, but for some reason the message "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool" is not suppressed, but displayed on the page.
Tell me, please, why? Can I solve my problem: "process any database errors in one place"?

errors and exceptions are not quite the same

You need to configure your connection to throw exceptions on errors. That way, failed prepare() will throw an exception rather than an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/why-does-this-pdo-statement-silently-fail

I don't see how it makes "Process any database errors in one place". On the contrary, when you need to run another query, you will have to process its errors in that another place. And so on. As many processing as many queries you have. Also, processing and suppressing are not the same. The latter is a very bad thing.

@ProfessorAbronsius in modern PHP, they are mostly the same.

@Álvaro-gonzález Thank you very much. I'm sorry I can't mark your answer as the solution.

@ÁlvaroGonzález one small correction, "That way, failed prepare() will throw an exception rather, rather than execute() throwing a generic exception because of empty prepare result().

@YourCommonSense You're totally right, that's how it behaves since PHP/7: https://3v4l.org/DoI2t

@WayMax No need to, your question already is linked to an answered question :)
